# What documents am I forced to sign?

Tags: united-states, virginia

I understand that there are some documents that I have to sign in order to have a benefit, for example, if I want to join a club I may need to sign the inscription form, but I can refuse to sign and although I wouldn't be able to become a member, there is no other legal consequence.

What kind of documents am I truly forced to sign if I don't want to face legal consequences?

Comment: Income tax return.

Comment: @phoong only if you have income.

Comment: None. Clearly, If you are physically or mentally impaired such that you are unable to sign then you cannot face sanction.

Comment: @DaleM I'm interested in answers even if they are conditional (because I may meet those conditions)

Comment: @DaleM there is no n in my name; I almost missed your reply.  The question is about documents that people can be forced to sign.  The existence of trivial exceptions does not render the question meaningless.

Comment: If you don't sign a will, you will have the legal consequence of your estate being intestate and going through probate.

Answer (score 1):

If you are stopped while driving and issued a ticket, say a speeding ticket for example, the officer always asks you to sign a form accepting the ticket (not an admission of guilt).

I've always suspected there might be some trouble (legal or otherwise) if someone refused to sign that document.

Comment: In Spain (where I was born) you are not forced to sign those, but I'm interested in US laws

Comment: Some states the police can arrest and you may have to go in front of a judge for a bail hearing.

Comment: @Hawkings: [Consider this](http://law.stackexchange.com/a/5433/794).